# shockwave activex plugin load flash then call video-js-swf function

Tags: flash, activex, video.js, externalinterface, shockwave

Env: win10,vs2015,adobe flash 26,.net framework 4.

I try to load [video-js-swf](https://github.com/videojs/video-js-swf) in MFC application in 'ActiveX' way.I alread load the .swf file with code in MFC.

```
CString str = _T("path.swf");
m_flash.LoadMovie(0, str);
```

But I can't use *m_flash.CallFunction()* to call the function inside *.swf* file,here is my code:

```
CString temp = _T("<invoke name=\"vjs_getProperty\" returntype=\"xml\"><arguments><string>defaultPlaybackRate</string></arguments></invoke>");
CString test = m_flash.CallFunction(temp);
```

the .swf project main code as:
[VideoJS.as](https://github.com/videojs/video-js-swf/blob/master/src/VideoJS.as)

Do anyone know how to solve this problem?How can I call function inside *.swf*?

Comment: Edit your question instead of adding info as comment.

Comment: There are two options, I think. First, knowing the nature of Flash content, it could be loaded but not yet ready. Thus, Flash content must probably signal first that it is ready. Second, you probably need to use **ExternalInterface** class to expose methods to the environment outside the Flash content.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figure it out.It's all about the xml string.
In my case, I use:

```
CString temp = _T("<invoke name=\"vjs_getProperty\" returntype=\"xml\"><arguments><string>defaultPlaybackRate</string></arguments></invoke>");
CString test = m_flash.CallFunction(temp);
```

It's report an error.But when I use:

```
CString temp = _T(R"(<invoke name="vjs_getProperty" returntype="xml"><arguments><string>defaultPlaybackRate</string></arguments></invoke>)");
CString test = m_flash.CallFunction(temp);
```

or:

```
CString temp = _T(R"(<invoke name="vjs_getProperty" returntype="xml"><arguments><string>!CDATA[[defaultPlaybackRate]]</string></arguments></invoke>)");
CString test = m_flash.CallFunction(temp);
```

It's OK.
I think the problem is the flash xml parser.The parser analyzes the string in strange way.By the way, seems `<arguments></arguments>` must in same line.

However, There is a new bug, memory leak. In visual studio debug mode,the application can't exit normally.
**Fix memory leak bug:**
change the code

https://github.com/videojs/video-js-swf/blob/master/src/com/videojs/providers/RTMPVideoProvider.as  (line:349)

```
if(_isPlaying){
     _ns.close();
     _isPlaying = false;
     _hasEnded = true;
     _reportEnded = true;
     _model.broadcastEvent(new VideoPlaybackEvent(VideoPlaybackEvent.ON_STREAM_CLOSE, {}));
    _throughputTimer.stop();
    _throughputTimer.reset();
}
```

REPLACE by

```
if(_isPlaying){
    _ns.close();
    _videoReference.attachNetStream(null);
    _isPlaying = false;
    _hasEnded = true;
    _reportEnded = true;
    _model.broadcastEvent(new VideoPlaybackEvent(VideoPlaybackEvent.ON_STREAM_CLOSE, {}));
    _throughputTimer.stop();
    _throughputTimer.reset();
    _videoReference.clear();
    _nc.close();
}
```

THEN

complie to .SWF file